# Subscript Out of Range in Macro

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code:

```
Workbooks("A").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("B2:BG2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.copy
Workbooks("C.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I am getting a Subscript Out of Range error at the first line.

Now error is at last line:

```
Workbooks("A.xlsm").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B2:BG2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.copy
Workbooks("C.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=45
lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Range("B" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
Workbooks("AB.xlsm").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B2:BG2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.copy
Workbooks("C.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Use of the first line assumes that the workbook "A" should be opened and contain sheet with name "Sheet1". Is it true for you?

Comment: I have an Excel named as A and Sheet1. I don't know whether that Excel is opened or not. Above is the code I have used

Answer (score 0):

Rather than syntax like:

```
Workbooks("A").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
```

use something like:

```
Workbooks("A.xlsm").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It worked. I have another one doubt, all the Excel sheet used should be in xlsm format ?

Comment: The workbook **containing the macro** should be in **.xlsm** or **.xls** format.

Comment: I am trying to copy two workbook values in one workbook. Now getting the error at last line.

Comment: Workbooks("A.xlsm").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B2:BG2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.copy
    Workbooks("C.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=45
    lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
    Workbooks("AB.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B2:BG2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.copy
    Workbooks("C.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Answer (score 0):

Try setting reference for workbook and worksheet first:

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Book1")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(1)

Windows(2).Activate
Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets(1)

ws1.Activate
ws1.Range("B2:BG2").Select
Selection.Copy

wb2.Activate
ws2.Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Thank you Ramesh.Can you please help me out in another error which I have posted

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question.

Try replacing :

```
Workbooks("C.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
```

with :

```
Workbooks("C.xlsm").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
```

**The reason behind this is:** when you call it in one line, you only want to activate the worksheet within that workbook; rather than activating both the workbook and the worksheet.

Another reason that *may* be causing trouble in this case is if you do not have a valid region selected in your `Workbooks("C.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")` when you try to copy into it. Try adding `Cells(1,1).Select` before pasting.

**I'll end with a better alternative that does not require activating workbooks/worksheets :**

The `.Copy` method has a "destination" parameter that may be set to be within any existing sheet of any open workbook. For example, you could replace the last 4 lines with something like :

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy _
                              (Workbooks("C.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"))
```